# Rotacionar imagem mantendo proporções

Tags: jquery, imagem, rotação

Preciso rotacionar uma imagem e manter a proporção em relação ao DIV pai sem que 'escape'. Só estou usando `rotate(90deg)` e as propriedades originais da imagem, como no exemplo.

Há alguns plugins que fazem isso mas contém muita coisa desnecessária, creio que algum ajuste no `CSS` resolva, mas não os atributos para manipular imagens dessa forma.

```js
$('button').click( function( event )
{
 $('img').css({ transform : 'rotate(90deg)' })
})
```

```css
div{border:#000000 solid 1px; width:200px; height:300px; text-align:center}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>girar</button>

<div>
<img src="http://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/v7sAAOSwQTVV7toe/s-l300.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Algum problema em resolver isto com javascript?

Comment: @SamirBraga, alguma sugestão?

Comment: PapaCharlie, possuo sim, dê uma olhada nesse JsFiddle que preparei, caso lhe sirva, avise-me... https://jsfiddle.net/qub8gLp6/1/

Comment: @SamirBraga, usando uma imagem maior não fica alinhado ao topo, mantive seu código, só mudei a imagem: https://jsfiddle.net/d56ynd12/

Comment: Observei o que disse e consegui resolver, com uma coisas a mais no javascript, nada muito complexo, apenas algumas propriedades css..https://jsfiddle.net/qub8gLp6/4/.  Dê uma olhada.